# Is there any way and any reason why one would introduce a sparsity constraint on a deep auto-encoder?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, deep-neural-networks, autoencoders

Is there any way and any reason why one would introduce a sparsity constraint on a deep autoencoder?

In particular, in deep autoencoders, the first layer often has more units than the dimensionality of the input.

Is there any case in the literature where a penalty is explicitly imposed for non-sparsity on this layer rather than relying solely on back-propagation and maybe weight decay as in a normal multilayer network?

I read [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf) tutorial on sparse autoencoders and searched a bit online, but I did not find any case where such a sparsity constraint is used in any other case than when only a single layer is used.

Comment: If you can make a single layer autoencoder with a sparcity constraint then you can take a few of those to make a stacked autoencoder. In keras it is a pain to use with the sequential model API,